# Docker build with WORKDIR makes Docker unable to find the image locally with Containerd beta enabled

Tags: docker, containerd

Minimal Dockerfile in `./Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM rockylinux:9

WORKDIR /opt/deploy
```

Build works fine:

```bash
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t minimal:test -f Dockerfile .
```

Run does not:

```bash
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker run --rm --platform linux/amd64 -it minimal:test
```

Error:

```
Unable to find image 'minimal:test' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/minimal:test": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Meanwhile, I can clearly see `minimal:test` in the output from `docker image ls`, and I can successfully run `docker image rm minimal:test`.

Weirder still, if I comment out the `WORKDIR` line, it works fine!

What am I dong wrong here?

I'm using Docker Desktop for Mac on MacOS 12.4:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.22, build 267d2e5
```

Edit: I had the `containerd` beta option enabled in Docker Desktop, which turned out to be the problem. Adding this to make it easier to search for this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empirically, this turned out to be a bug in the experimental "Containerd" option in Docker Desktop, possibly related to lazy-loading of images. Disabling that option and restarting the Docker daemon fixed the problem.

Comment: Have you authoritative information about this fact?

Comment: @RaphaëlColantonio no, but disabling the option fixed it. I was tempted to close this question as "not reproducible" but I'm sure someone somewhere had the same problem and would benefit from finding this.